# Given $A^3$ is similar to $B^3$ and $rank(A)=rank(A^2),rank(B)=rank(B^2)$ , prove that $A$ is similar to $B$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $$A,B\in M_3(C)$$
and  $$rank(A)=rank(A^2),rank(B)=rank(B^2) $$ 
and  $A^3$ is similar to $B^3$.

and all eigenvalue of $A,B$ are real number

can I prove that $A$ is similar to $B$?

What does the rank imply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** The rank implies that in both $A$ and $B$, the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue $0$ coincides with the algebraic multiplicity.  That is: in their Jordan forms, if $A$ and $B$ have $0$ as an eigenvalue, then the associated Jordan block has size at most $1$.

Comment: How do you handle the case where $A,B$ don't have eigenvalue $0$?

Comment: @quasi one Jordan block at a time. The statement holds over $M_n$, not just $M_3$. The fact that the eigenvalues are real is important.

Comment: A neat approach is to consider an "analytic" cube-root function around a point.

Comment: I don't follow. Do you mean some kind of matrix power series?

Comment: @quasi yeah, but that's not necessary.  All you really **need** to do is show that for any Jordan block of a non-zero eigenvalue, $J^3$ is a similar to a Jordan block of the same shape (but of a new eigenvalue).